# WPF Xaml pages not loading in Visual studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am working with visual studio 2010 buiding a wpf application and none of my xaml pages in ANY wpf project is working, I get the error message saying -

Error 1 Could not load file or assembly 'ISymWrapper, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I tried re-installing visual studio, no use :/. Also, googling gives me very vague results. Anyone else has had/solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your WPF projects set to .NET 4.0 Client Profile? I read that ISymWrapper is not included in the 4.0 Client Profile (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.symbolstore.symwriter.aspx)

If that's not the problem, then something might be wrong with the .NET Framework on your PC. If possible, try to reinstall (http://www.microsoft.com/net/download)

Comment: Also, visual studio was working perfectly fine a few days back. Didn't change anything..

Comment: What happens if you open a blank Visual Studio and start a new WPF project?